# ¿Como ocultar conexión del webconfig usando EntityFramework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, web.config

Actualmente estoy usando EntitiFramework, lo cual la conexión a la base de datos se escribe en el web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-EF5-20200420114004.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-EF5-20200420114004;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="bd_ejemplo" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BD.csdl|res://*/BD.ssdl|res://*/BD.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=xxxxxx;user id=id_1;password=id_1;port=49001;database=bd_pruebas;persistsecurityinfo=True;Convert Zero Datetime=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Quería saber si existe la posibilidad de ocultar los datos de conexión de la base de datos(nombre servidor, clave,etc).
Quizas haya la forma de colocarlo en una variable definida en algun archivo de Clase, y en el web.config llamarlo con esa variable.

Anteriormente trabajaba con datareader, en donde la conexión la establecia en un archivo de clase, por ejemplo:

```
 public class Clase_Conexion
    {

        public MySqlConnection con;

        public void conectar()
        {
            con = new MySqlConnection("server=xxxxx;user id=xxx;password=xxx;database=xxx;port=3306;Allow User Variables=true"); // LOCALHOST
            con.Open();
        }
        //metodo para cerrar
        public void cerrar()
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Quizás, existe la forma de redireccionar la conexión por EntityFramework en algún archivo clase y llamar la conexión desde ahí.

La idea de esto, es poder proteger u ocultar la conexión de la  base de datos que está en el web.config.

Si alguien tiene algún ejemplo, se lo agradecería.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos, si no quieres que se tenga la información de la BD, lo que se utiliza es el cifrado de secciones del web.config.

Esto implica que desde el servidor en que se ejecutará la aplicación, se debe utuilizar el comando reg_iis del siguiente modo:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\applicationFolder"
```

Sólo hay que colocar la ruta en la que se encuentra publicada tu aplicación.

Es  importante resaltar que esto se debe ejecutar en el servidor, no en el equipo de desarrollo.

Answer (score -1):

Doy por supuesto que usas *MySQL* como proveedor de base de datos.

Cuando creas tu `Dbcontext` puedes sobreescribir el método `OnConfiguring`, que toma por argumento un objeto de tipo `DbContextOptionsBuilder`.

El paquete de extensiones de *MySQL* para *Entity Framework* ([MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore)) extiende el objeto `DbContextOptionsBuilder` con el método `UseMySQL` que toma por argumento la *connection string*.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
      optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=library;user=user;password=password");
}
```

Te dejo la documentación de [*MySQL para Entity Framework*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html).

Espero que sirva.

Comment: VRoxa, esto no responde a la necesidad de OP, que es _"ocultar los datos de conexión de la base de datos"_.

Comment: Por supuesto que lo oculta. Quiere evitar tener que ponerlos en *web.config*. Este método te da la flexibilidad de poder rescatar la *connection string* de donde quieras, tenerla encriptada, etc.